# Angular2 - NgFor with multiple checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor

I´m trying to create a table that has multiple checkboxes with different states (some are true, other false).

In this table i have 'Save' button to featch all elements with his state.

The code is like:

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form)">
  <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
         class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{'name-placeholder' | translate}}</th>
        <th>{{'action' | translate}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let card of cardsDashboard;let i=index">
        <td>{{card.text}}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkDashboard" [(ngModel)]="card[i]"
                     (ngModelChange)="card[i].activate==true?'true':'false'" [checked]="card.activate">
              <span class="label-text"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right ">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">{{'save' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The first problem: 'Save' button doesn´t update the state of elements.

Second problem: The checkboxes doesn´t show default state. Checkbox is null.

So the question is: How can i do a ngfor with checkboxes and show the state and update it?

**----UPDATE: ARRAY-----**

```
0:
activate: true
cardType: 1
id: 1
text: "Contadores"
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 2, text: "Alarmas", cardType: 2, activate: false}
2: {id: 3, text: "Consumo día anterior", cardType: 3, activate: false}
3: {id: 4, text: "Consumo del mes anterior", cardType: 4, activate: false}
4: {id: 5, text: "Elementos instalados la ultima semana", cardType: 5, activate: false}
5: {id: 6, text: "Elementos que han comunicado hoy", cardType: 6, activate: false}
```

Comment: you can use form array

Comment: change [(ngModel)]="card[i]" to [(ngModel)]="card.activate" and no need to have (ngModelChange) and [checked]

Comment: @Arash I i use 'card' all elements has same model so i can´t take individual state.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre can you past your JSON data ?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** I'm feel a bit stupid ::glups::

```
[(ngModel)]="card[i].activate" //<--WRONG

[(ngModel)]="card.activate" //<--OK
```

and forget (ngModelChange) and [checked].

Looking the Question, really you has not make nothing more

Normally, we can two things:

the values in an array, e.g. values=["uno","tres"] or values=[true,false,true,false]
A list of "checked options"=["uno","dos","tres","cuatro"]

So, in an array we can has

```
this.options.forEach((x,index)=>{
   this.card[index].activate=value[index]
   //or 
   //   this.card[index].activate=value.indexOf(x)>=0

})
```

Comment: Return ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'activate' of undefined

Comment: I had an error typ (active by activated), just corrected in the code

Comment: Can you write a example in stackbklitz?

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre, ::sorry::, you're correct is card.activate, you has your code in a stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kssyli?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: sorry -again- you need give a different name to the input: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkDashboard{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="card.activate">` -see the {{i}}-